# UNIX find for finding file names not paired by

Tags: unix, find

Is there a simple way to recursively find all files in a directory hierarchy, that do not have a matching file with a different extension?

For example the directory has a bunch of files ending in .dat

I want to find the .dat files that do not have an accompanying .out file.

I have a while loop that checks each entry, but that is slow for long lists...

I am using GNU find.

Comment: You should consider asking this question on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
find . -name "*.dat" -print | sort > column1.txt
find . -name "*.out" -print | sort > column2.txt
diff column1.txt column2.txt
```

I haven't tested it, but I think it's probably close to what you're asking for.

Comment: I had to add a bunch of bells and whistles, but that was a good start, thanks...
  find . -print | grep -Fi '.dat' | grep -vFi '.dat.' | sort | sed -e 's/\.dat//g' > column1.txt
  find . -print | grep -Fi '.out' | grep -vFi '.out.' | sort | sed -e 's/\.out//g' > column2.txt
  sdiff -s column1.txt column2.txt | grep -F '<' | cut -f1 -d"<" > c12diff.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name '*.dat' -printf "[ -f %p ] || echo %p\n" | sed 's/\.dat/.out/' | sh
```

Comment: Thanks amit_g, but I think your solution fails due to spaces in filenames?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a bunch of bells and whistles to the 1st solution, but that was a good start, thanks...

find . -print | grep -Fi '.dat' | grep -vFi '.dat.' | sort | sed -e 's/.dat//g' > column1.txt
  find . -print | grep -Fi '.out' | grep -vFi '.out.' | sort | sed -e 's/.out//g' > column2.txt
  sdiff -s column1.txt column2.txt | grep -F '<' | cut -f1 -d"<" > c12diff.txt